# Can anybody vouch for PubSure?

Tags: disreputable-publishers, scams

A few days ago I uploaded a pre-print to arXiv. Today I got an email from  a service called *PubSure* offering to evaluate the manuscript with AI (?) and give me a score on how "publishable" (?) it is. In their own words:

> PubSURE is a super cool AI-powered solution that evaluates research manuscripts and provides a score to indicate their submission readiness.

I signed up to check it out (although my pre-print is already accepted for publication) and they ask you to upload the article (Doc and Docx files) to evaluate it (which I did not do).

I'm getting scam vibes from this one (but I could be wrong!). Anybody heard from this service before (perhaps even used it)?

Comment: Hmmm. If they call themselves "super cool" they are probably a scam.

Comment: Closing this as per [this Meta consensus](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4062/7734).

Comment: It's a scam.  Any service offering to provide you with a certificate you can send to a journal is a scam, because editors do not consider these certificates.

Comment: I can’t believe *this* question got closed when it was asked first

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Note that it wasn't closed as a duplicate - it was closed as it was asking for an assessment of a commercial service. The second question avoided that pitfall by being more general. The duplicate link was added afterwards.